# Is it C++ for loop had require run time?

Tags: python, c++

I had one `c++` program that inside for loop, calling a function.
The function is doing a heavy process, it is embedded with `python` and performing image processing.

My question is, why can it only run at the first instance of the variable?

Main function (I only show the part of code require in this title):

```
int main(){
for(int a = 0;a<5;a++){
    for(int b=0;b<5;b++){

// I want every increment it go to PyRead() function, doing image processing, and compare 
  if(PyRead()==1){
             // some application might be occur
         }
         else {
         }
     }
}
```

`PyRead()` function, the function in `c++` to go into `python` environment performing image processing:

```
bool PyRead(){


string data2;
Py_Initialize();    


        PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hahahahahawwwwwwwwwwwww' ");
        char filename[] = "testcapture";


        PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
        PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

        PyObject * moduleObj = PyImport_ImportModule(filename);
         if (moduleObj)
         {
            PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hahahahaha' ");
            char functionName[] = "test";
            PyObject * functionObj = PyObject_GetAttrString(moduleObj, functionName);
            if (functionObj)
            {
               if (PyCallable_Check(functionObj))
               {
                  PyObject * argsObject = PyTuple_New(0);
                  if (argsObject)
                  {
                     PyObject * resultObject = PyEval_CallObject(functionObj, argsObject);
                     if (resultObject)
                     {
                        if ((resultObject != Py_None)&&(PyString_Check(resultObject))) 
                        {
                            data2 = PyString_AsString(resultObject);
                        }
                        Py_DECREF(resultObject);
                     }
                     else if (PyErr_Occurred()) PyErr_Print();

                     Py_DECREF(argsObject);
                  }
               }
               Py_DECREF(functionObj);
            }
            else PyErr_Clear();

            Py_DECREF(moduleObj);
         }
Py_Finalize();


 std::cout << "The Python test function returned: " << data2<< std::endl;




cout << "Data2 \n" << data2;

if(compareID(data2) == 1)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
}
```

This is second time I ask this question in stack overflow. I hope this time this question will be more clear!

I can successful compile with no error.

**When I run the program, I realize at `a=0`, `b=0` it will go to `PyRead()` function and return value, after that it go to `a=0`, `b=1`, at that moment the whole program will end.

It supposes to go to `PyRead()` function again, but it does not do that and straight ending the program.**

**I must strongly mention that `PyRead()` function needed a long time to run (30seconds).**

I had no idea what happens, seeking for somehelp. Please focus on the **Bold** part to understand my question.

Thanks.

Comment: So in other words your program crashes the second time it calls PyRead?

Comment: @immibis ya ... It crash

Comment: Your code is laughing at you!

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie why?

Comment: @BeginProgramLife We struggled in our application to call `PyInitialize()` multiple times. Actually, it worked somehow but we recognized increasing memory-leaks at every call (although we didn't forget to call `PyFinalize()` also). Finally, we decided to call it once only (at begin of our application). (I didn't like the approach because we intended to have separate "Python sessions".) My colleage did a tedious web-search before to solve that problem another way but all he found was the hint to do it the way we finally did.

Comment: @Scheff PyInitialize() need call multiple time, because as you mention I want have a seperate Python sessions... Is it had any way to solve this?

Comment: @BeginProgramLife No, actually we couldn't solve it really. My colleage made a workaround to put our Python code into wrapper code which allows to remove the artifacts (global variables, functions, imported modules) as best as possible. It seems that system libraries of Python are stored in global variables that cannot be cleaned up fully. He carefully handled `Py_INCREF()/Py_DECREF()` but this didn't help. (May be, he didn't it carefully enough - but thus the technical problem resulted in a maintenance issue - killing the schedule of our development timeline...)

Comment: PyInitialize could not possibly initialize different Python sessions if its life depended on it. You may want to research Py_NewInterpreter.

Comment: @BeginProgramLife because of your prints :)

Answer (score 1):

See the comment in https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Finalize

> **Ideally**, this frees all memory allocated by the Python interpreter.
>
> Dynamically loaded extension modules loaded by Python are not unloaded.
>
> Some extensions **may not work properly** if their initialization routine is called more than once

It seems your module, does not play well with this function.

A workaround can be - create the script on the fly and call it with python subprocess.